# SQL Server 2012: Constraint has NULL for name. How can I drop this?

Tags: sql-server

I am not sure how this happened, but I have a PRIMARY KEY constraint on one of my tables and the name is NULL. I discovered it because I had to drop/recreate the table, and when I tried to add the PRIMARY KEY, the system responded that the constraint already existed.

I executed the following:

```
SELECT i.object_id, i.name, i.type_desc
FROM sys.indexes i
INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON i.object_id = t.object_id
AND t.name = N'Organization'
```

and the result is:

```
object_id  name                                  type_desc
1570377655 NULL                                  HEAP
1570377655 IX_Organization_OwnedByOrganizationId NONCLUSTERED
```

I tried dropping and recreating the table several times and each time the index is there. How can I drop the constraint?

Comment: The `NULL` isn't a constraint. that row just indicates that the table is a heap (no clustered index). RE: "the system responded that the constraint already existed." this may be a constraint on another table with the same name as you are attempting to use. Script out the table and show us that and the script that you are trying to run and the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find the index you are trying to add using the following query:

```
SELECT  [Table] = t.[name]
    , [Index] = i.[name]
    , i.*
FROM    sys.indexes i
INNER   JOIN    sys.tables t
    ON  t.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
```

Martin has the right answer to index you find with the NULL name.